# How can I have 1 line per id, instead of 2 in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know what is the 1st and the 2nd page (and so on) visited by a user in a session.
I already managed to get the flow of interaction through the row_n function.

However, I want a column with the flow of the interaction, but, taking the following example, instead of 2 lines I want 1 line with FIRST and SECOND columns filled up.

[image]

Here's my code:

````
SELECT
    ID,
    PAGE_TITLE,
    FIRST,
    SECOND
FROM (
SELECT
    distinct
    concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) as id,
    page_title,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS interaction_number,
    iff(interaction_number = 1, page_title, '') as first,
    iff(interaction_number = 2, page_title, '') as second
FROM CDP_GA4_RAW.RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT
where id = '1000002360.16826696111682669619'
GROUP BY page_title, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id, ga_session_number
order by id)
;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like:

````
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN interaction_number = 1 THEN page_title ELSE '' END) as first,
    MAX(CASE WHEN interaction_number = 2 THEN page_title ELSE '' END) as second,
    MAX(CASE WHEN interaction_number = 3 THEN page_title ELSE '' END) as third,
    MAX(CASE WHEN interaction_number = 4 THEN page_title  ELSE '' END) as fourth
FROM (
SELECT
    concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) as id,
    page_title ,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(EVENT_TIMESTAMP) AS EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(event_timestamp)) AS interaction_number
FROM CDP_GA4_RAW.RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT
GROUP BY page_title , event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id, ga_session_number
order by id)
group by id
;```
````

Answer (score 1):

so with a CTE for fake data, we can reproduce you example:

```
with RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id, page_title, event_timestamp, ga_session_number) as (
    select * from values
    ('1.', 10, 'aaa', 100, 1000),
    ('1.', 10, 'aaa', 101, 1000),
    ('1.', 10, 'aaa', 102, 1000)
)
SELECT
    ID,
    PAGE_TITLE,
    FIRST,
    SECOND
FROM (
    SELECT
        distinct
        concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) as id,
        page_title,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS interaction_number,
        iff(interaction_number = 1, page_title, '') as first,
        iff(interaction_number = 2, page_title, '') as second
    FROM RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT
    where id = '1.10'
    GROUP BY page_title, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id, ga_session_number
    order by id
);
```

| ID | PAGE_TITLE | FIRST | SECOND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | aaa | aaa |  |
| 1.1 | aaa |  | aaa |
| 1.1 | aaa |  |  |

Notes: 'ORDER BY' should be avoided in none final statements, as it is meaningless, but costs compute time. `DISTINCT` should not be needed, as you are doing a `GROUP BY`, but you are grouping by a column (`ga_session_number`) that is not present in the SELECTION, nor in the ROW_NUMBER, so it is possible you could get the same selected results and then throw some data away (unless ga_session_id and ga_session_number are locked together?).

So given you are ranking the page_titles, first/second this implies there is some change in these, but you are also grouping by these, so it seems you are wanting to select all distinct pages visited, and then the first/seconds also.

To be honest, I cannot guess, how you are want to deduplicate the data, as you have too many conflicting strategies used.

BUT there is a function [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nth_value) which does what you have done, like so:

```
with RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id, page_title, event_timestamp, ga_session_number) as (
    select * from values
    ('1.', '10', 'aaa', 100, 1000),
    ('1.', '10', 'aab', 101, 1000),
    ('1.', '10', 'aac', 102, 1000)
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) as id,
    page_title,
    NTH_VALUE(page_title, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) as first,
    NTH_VALUE(page_title, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) as second
FROM RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT
;
```

[image]